# How to know the chosen GRUB2 entry?

Tags: boot, grub2

Is there a file that contains the option of the GRUB2 menu that was chosen for the current boot? This question is different from obtaining the Kernel boot sequence, for example, to differentiate two boot options with the same boot sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I belive if you have set the grub to save the default grub boot, like so:

**/etc/default/grub:**

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

Then you will find it in the /boot/grub2/grubenv file

# more /boot/grub2/grubenv

```
# GRUB Environment Block
saved_entry=CentOS Linux (3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64) 7 (Core)
```

For more info, please go here
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Environment-block.html

Comment: That is my /etc/default/grub configuration. However the /boot/grub/grubenv file just shows 
# GRUB Environment Block
next_entry = 
#######...#########

Comment: Since your question was about grub2, did you check /boot/grub2/grubenv?

Comment: you could also check the output of this command:

**grub2-editenv list**

Comment: I checked **/boot/grub/grubenv** as I'm using Mint, and grub2 commands are named grub, even when the GRUB version is 2.02